# Joining varchar and nvarchar

Tags: sql

I'm comparing account numbers in two different databases to make sure the account exists in both. The account field in one database is `nvarchar` and the other it's `varchar`. I do a cast to cast them both to `varchar(12)` and join them to see where there isn't a match. If there is an account number with less than 12 characters then it thinks it's not a match. I'm assuming the extra characters in each field are causing the issue?

```
table1 - accountnumber(nvarchar(255))
table2 - accountnumber(varchar(20))

select * from
table1
left outer join table2 on table2.accountnumber = table1.accountnumber
```

In this one example, both tables have an account with the number 12345678, but the join isn't working. I'm not sure if it's data type mismatch or white space or something else.

--Added--
I should add that the data in table2 actually originates from an Oracle database where it's stored as a varchar2(12 byte). I import it into a SQL Server database where it's stored as a varchar(20). I'm not sure if this makes a difference.

Comment: What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: joining two tables
table1 - accountnumber(nvarchar(255))
table2 - accountnumber(varchar(20))

select * from
table1
left outer join table2 on table2.accountnumber = table1.accountnumber

Comment: Can we assume you are using SQL Server?

Comment: Try to cast first column to varchar(20)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where you are having a problem.  This query should return matching account numbers (no need to CAST):

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable 
   JOIN YourOtherTable ON YourTable.AccountNumber = YourOtherTable.AccountNumber
```

If your data has spaces, you can TRIM your data depending on your RDBMS -- LTRIM and RTRIM for SQL Server.

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable 
   JOIN YourOtherTable ON RTRIM(LTRIM(YourTable.AccountNumber)) = RTRIM(LTRIM(YourOtherTable.AccountNumber))
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8491a/3).

Good luck.

Comment: But the sql server execution plan will show Type conversion may affect seek plan. So how to handle that. I mean for optimization of the query.

Answer (score 1):

Your query works fine. This is perhaps a character encoding issue. Try using `collate`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2290796/1349295) previous SO answer which might help.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into absolutely same case, I had even *two* sibling queries (one created as a copy of another), which both had this problem. Collation and types were no issue here.

Finally after a LOT of testing, one of the queries started to work without aparent changes, just re-written. When I retyped the IN part of the second query, it started to work too.
So there was a problem with a **hidden character** accidentally typed somewhere in the query.